# Can ViewController be generic which contains IBOutlets etc?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, decodable

Can my viewcontroller be generic and still contain IBOutlet?

```
class AViewController<T> : SuperViewController, Decodable where T : Decodable {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!

    var pop : T?

}
```

will this impleemntation works? it throws me an error. Type AViewController does not conform to decodable.Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to declare that `AViewController` conforms to `Decodable`? You would never attempt to encode or decode a view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your response. Infact my pop variable will be a custom pop up/alert which can be of different types. hence wanted to use generics instead of Any or AnyObject. Let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want your T (not your VC) to be Decodable?  If you do, you should use `class AViewController<T: Decodable> { }`. That being said, generic VCs don't seem to work with storyboards. But I don't use storyboards so I may be wrong.

Comment: @TechnoGeezer Your use of generics and your use of Decodable don't seem to have anything to do with each other. Even if you want `T` to be `Decodable`, that has nothing to do with the fact that you also needlessly declared that the view controller itself is `Decodable`.

Comment: @KubeeThanks Kubee, Exactly what I was looking for. But yes I am using storyboard, but I can give a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `, Decodable`. There is no reason to indicate that the view controller class itself conforms to `Decodable`.

Your error is gone with:

```
class AViewController<T> : SuperViewController where T : Decodable {
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!

    var pop : T?
}
```

This is completely independent of why you are also declaring that `T` must be `Decodable`. That's a completely separate question I'm not going to address.

Comment: Completely agree with you. I might not even need that to be a decodable. Its just that I need it for comparison for incoming objects in next iterations.

Comment: You don't need `Decodable` to compare. Make it `Comparable` if that's what you need.

Comment: Agree on this one. Will be go back and revisit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

View controllers that contain `IBOutlet`s are view controllers that you will manipulate in Interface Builder. There are two problems that you face with this.

1. An Interface Builder view controller is created using the required `init(coder:)` initializer, which cannot instantiate generic objects, as it does not have any context in which it knows what `T` should be at run time.
2. When you create an instance of `AViewController` in code you will specify the concrete type

`let aVC = AViewController<String>()`

but you cannot do such a thing in the Identity Inspector in IB. This is not allowed:

[image]

What you can do is create a storyboard specific view controller that inherits from your generic view controller, but specifies the concrete type

```
class AStringViewController: AViewController<String> {
}
```

And use `AStringViewController` in IB in the identity inspector and hook up the outlets as required.

If you find that this isn't really what you want and your view controller needs to be more dynamic then you will have to create your view controller in code and you will not be able to use outlets.

Another alternative is to have a non-generic view controller with your outlets and use child view controllers that are created in code that have the generics you need.